# Which is the best way of Routing in a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

Which is the best way of Routing in a Flutter App?
I've tried named routes, routes array, flutter navigation 2.0. But I am still not sure which is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigator 1.0 and 2.0 are usable. None is deprecated.

For mobile app only Navigator 1.0 is the best, I use onGenerateRoute field from MaterialApp and that's all I can handle all my routes and deep links. Some times, I used the Navigator widget for specific routes in app page but it's rare.

Answer (score 3):

### [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations) suggests using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package for Navigation.

---

#### Explanation:

##### Limitations of trivial approach

> Although named routes can handle deep links, the behavior is always the same and can’t be customized. When a new deep link is received by the platform, Flutter pushes a new Route onto the Navigator regardless where the user currently is.

##### Suggested Better Approach

> Flutter applications with advanced navigation and routing requirements (such as a web app that uses direct links to each screen, or an app with multiple Navigator widgets) should use a routing package such as **go_router** that can parse the route path and configure the Navigator whenever the app receives a new deep link.

---

##### Reference questions regarding go_router:

- [Flutter: go_router how to pass multiple parameters to other screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976031/flutter-go-router-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-other-screen/74813803#74813803)
- [Go_Router Pass Object to new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741283/go-router-pass-object-to-new-route/74813017#74813017)