# Flutter: go_router how to pass multiple parameters to other screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, flutter-go-router

In a vanilla flutter I use to pass multiple parameters to other screen like this:

```
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => CatalogFilterPage(
                                          list: list,
                                          bloc: bloc,
                                        )))
```

Pretty simple and easy. I can pass 2 needed parameters, list and bloc. After use it in CatalogFilterPage.

Now after switching to go_router and looking through [documentation](https://gorouter.dev/) I can't seem to find how to pass multiple data. Even passing single object seems not that good:

```
    onTap: () =>
              context.pushNamed('SelectedCatalogItem', extra: list[index]),
```

And in router I have to use casting to set correct type:

```
    builder: (context, state) => SelectedCatalogItem(
                    item: state.extra as ListItemsModel,
                  ),
```

It was fine for single parameter. But now I don't have an idea how to pass multiple parameters. How can I do it? Is even passing parameters, like models, as an extra is right way?

P.S. I know that you can pass parameters as `context.pushNamed('CatalogFilterPage', params: ___)`, but `params` has type of Map<String, String> witch not let me pass model's

Comment: you can refer to this doc - https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 169, accepted):

##### Edit: Breaking changes in [Go_router 10.0.0](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vjupshmFJtfGSOppZxp7Tzkq7dotcLxCcpdluuNYe1o/edit)

[image]

##### Edit: Breaking changes in [Go_router 7.0.0](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10Xbpifbs4E-zh6YE5akIO8raJq_m3FIXs6nUGdOspOg/edit)

[image]

#### In NutShell

```
Below Go Router 7  i.e < 7.0.0 use `params`, `queryParams`
Go Router 7 to 10  i.e 7.0.0 <=, < 10.0.0 use `pathParameters`, `queryParameters`
Above Go Router 10 i.e 10.0.0 <= use `pathParameters`, `uri.queryParameters`
```

### Summary:

There are three ways: `pathParameters`, `queryParameters`, `extra`

1. Using `pathParameters`

   - When you know the number of parameters beforehand
   - Usage : `path = '/routeName/:id1/:id2'`
2. Using `uri.queryParameters`

   - When you are not sure about the number of parameters
   - Usage : `path = '/routeName'`
3. Using `extra`

   - When you want to pass `object`

---

### Explanation:

#### 1. Using `pathParameters`

When you know number of params beforehand use `pathParameters` prop in `context.goNamed()`

###### Define it as:

```dart
GoRoute(
  path: '/sample/:id1/:id2',  //  Defination of params in the path is important
  name: 'sample',
  builder: (context, state) => SampleWidget(
    id1: state.pathParameters['id1'],
    id2: state.pathParameters['id2'],
  ),
),
```

###### Call it as:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    var param1 = "param1";
    var param2 = "param2";
    context.goNamed("sample", pathParameters: {'id1': param1, 'id2': param2});
  },
  child: const Text("Hello"),
),
```

###### Receive it as:

```dart
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String? id1;
  String? id2;
  SampleWidget({super.key, this.id1, this.id2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
  }
}
```

---

#### 2. Using `uri.queryParameters`

Use the `queryParameters` in `context.goNamed()` ex: `context.goNamed('sample', queryParameters: {'id1': 'param1'})` function or
simply add params after the ? in the URL of `context.go()` ex: `context.go('/sample?id1=param1')`.
The best thing about `queryParameters` is that you don't have to explicitly define them in your route path and can easily access them using the `state.uri.queryParameters` method. You can add miscellaneous user-related data as a query parameter.

###### Define it as :

```dart
GoRoute(
  name: "sample",
  path: "/sample",          
  builder: (context, state) => SampleWidget(
      id1: state.uri.queryParameters['id1'],
      id2: state.uri.queryParameters['id2'],
  ),
)
```

###### Call it as:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    var param1 = "param1";
    var param2 = "param2";
    context.goNamed("sample", queryParameters: {'id1': param1, 'id2': param2});
    // context.go("/sample?id1=$param1&id2=$param2");  or like this.
  },
  child: const Text("Hello"),
),
```

###### Receive it as:

```dart
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String? id1;
  String? id2;
  SampleWidget({super.key, this.id1, this.id2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
  }
}
```

---

#### 3. Using `extra`

Use this when you want to pass a `model/object` between routes

```dart
GoRoute(
  path: '/sample',
  builder: (context, state) {
    Sample sample = state.extra as Sample; //  casting is important
    return GoToScreen(object: sample);
  },
),
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74813017/13431819 for passing `object` between routes

Comment: if anyone having issues accessing the **extra** object in the **State** then you can do this by using **widget** getter like this **widget.object**

Comment: I'd add something to this answer, maybe it's a good design to parse/extract/cast the parameters in `GoRouterWidgetBuilder builder: (context, state) {}` but also could access the state inside the screen by calling `GoRouterState.of(context)` to get `params`, `queryParams` and `extra`

Comment: Do I need to use `namedRoute` if I want to use `queryParams`? I was wondering why I can't simply pass it using standard route.

Comment: For query parameters, GoRouterState no longer has queryParameters accessible directly from `state`. Instead, use `state.uri.queryParameters`

Comment: How to pass multiple objects please?

Comment: @Faz create a model that contains list of objects can be array or key value pairs then parse it , similar to parsing to and from model during API Request

Answer (score 8):

I am new to Flutter, but here is how I passed multiple parameters/arguments to a route with GoRouter using the `extra` property of `context.push()`:

```dart
// navigate to /my-path, pass 2 arguments to context.state.extra
context.push("/my-path", extra: {"arg1": firstArg, "arg2": secondArg});
```

Then, inside my route:

```dart
// ...
// Use arguments in builder of the GoRoute
GoRoute(
  path: '/dashboard',
  builder: (context, state) {
    Map<String, MyCustomType> args =
      state.extra as Map<String, MyCustomType>;
    return MyWidget(arg1: args["arg1"]!, arg2: args["arg2"]!);
  }
),
// ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with my own code. In my case, i want to parse `MenuModels` from `HomeScreen` to another screen (`ItemScreen`):

```
context.push(
    '/item-screen',
    extra: widget.menuModels,
),
```

And in my `route.dart`

```
GoRoute(
    path: '/item-screen',
    builder: (context, state) {
        MenuModels models = state.extra as MenuModels;
        return ItemScreen(
            menuModels: models,
        );
    },
),
```

Comment: what about If we have more than one extraItem? For example, think the itemscreen has both menu models and usermodels? so, how we can push?

Comment: Use `List<Object>` as your extra and and pass it as `extra: [object1, object2]`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [go_router](https://gorouter.dev/parameters#extra-parameter) documentation we can see that:

> The extra object is useful if you'd like to simply pass along **a single object** to the builder function w/o passing an object identifier via a URI and looking up the object from a store.

What you can do instead is pass in the id/name of the 'SelectedCatalogItem' as **params** and form the Object later on (if possible). The 'params' parameter lets us pass in more than one fields

```
onTap: () => context.pushNamed('SelectedCatalogItem',
                  params: {"id":list[index].id.toString(),"name":list[index].name}),
```

Then in the builder function of the GoRouter we can do:

```
GoRoute(
        path: 'selectedCatalogItem/view/:id/:name',
        name: 'SelectedCatalogItem',
        builder: (context, state){
          int id = int.parse(state.params['id']!);
          String name = state.params['name']!;
          // use id and name to your use...
        });
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error when using your code: `missing param "id" for /all/:name/:id` How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

*Completing the example above (by @Agni Gari)*

**3. Using extra** `context.goNamed()`

> Use this when you want to pass a model/object between routes

**Define it as:**

```
GoRoute(
    path: '/sample',
    name: 'sample',
    builder: (context, state) {
      Sample sample = state.extra as Sample; // -> casting is important
      return GoToScreen(object: sample);
    },
  ),
```

**Call it as:**

```
Sample sample = Sample(attributeA: "True",attributeB: "False",boolValue: false);
context.goNamed("sample",extra:sample );
```

**Receive it as:**

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
Sample? object;
SampleWidget({super.key, this.object});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
  }
}
```