# How can you change URL in the web browser without named routes

Tags: flutter

Since ["named routes are no longer recommended for most applications"](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#using-named-routes) how can you change the URL in web browser when you push a new route onto Navigator stack?

E.g. URL is `http://localhost:37291/#/` and after performing

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
  );
```

I would want it to change to `http://localhost:37291/#/secondRoute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same official [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#using-the-router) you have provided there is link for the [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router), which is preferred by flutter team

You can use the `path` property of `GoRoute` to achieve the desired `url`

---

Initial setup:

```
// GoRouter configuration
final _router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/secondRoute', //  here you can add the path
      builder: (context, state) => SecondScreen(), // This is the desired screen you would want to go to 
    ),
  ],
);
```

Now your url when routing to `SecondScreen` would be `http://localhost:37291/#/secondRoute`

If you want to have the very same functionality you had with `Navigator` stack you need to implement stuff around `Router` class. Find out more in [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade). You could possibly refer [this article](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-navigator2/) for the same.

---

Further reference:

[Flutter: go_router how to pass multiple parameters to other screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976031/flutter-go-router-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-other-screen/74813803#74813803)

Comment: Yep, been checking it, but it seems with `go_router` you can't do various things (including pushing named route as in question), it's very limitted. I think now you have to implement all the stuff around `Router` class.

Comment: It is now under flutter's care, as it is officially stated in the docs to use `go_router` and there are lot many updates which are seen in the `go_router` so yeah,I agree, we have to implement all the stuff around `GoRouter` class

Comment: More like `Router` class if we want to have the same functionality we had before with `Navigator` stack.

Comment: yes , indeed !!!

Comment: Good article: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade Will need to go through all of this....

Comment: You could even refer these https://dev.to/codemagicio/a-beginners-guide-to-gorouter-in-flutter-24ec and https://blog.devgenius.io/guide-to-go-router-flutter-1ddcfa56d39c these are of great help if you are using `go_router` hope it helps!

Comment: Could i possibly draw your attention to this post https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-navigator2/, this is recent post, the post you suggested seems to be 2 years old. And lot of things have changed in this span

Comment: I have updated my post for the completeness with the above mentioned code. Hope it helps