# How to pass optional List argument through go_router?

Tags: flutter

I want to pass an optional List argument through go_router.
Here's my class with an optional `List<int>` argument:

```
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
    List<int>? genres;
    Loading({Key? key, this.genres}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}
```

And the router:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: [
    GoRoute(name: 'loading', path: '/', builder: (context, state) {
            List<int> genres = state.extra as List;
            return Loading(genres: genres);
        },  
    ), 

  ...
 
]);
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error message:

> A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of
> type 'List<int>'.

How can I fix that?

Comment: hmmm, as far as i used go_router i havent actually encounter passing list, but have you tried? setting the List<int?> genres; to List<dynamic> in order to match up the data will allow go router to pass on states

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting the `state.extra` property to a `List<int>`.

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: [
    GoRoute(name: 'loading', path: '/', builder: (context, state) {
            List<int> genres = state.extra as List<int>? ?? [];
            return Loading(genres: genres);
        },  
    ),     
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mapper for pars data if sure it `state.extra` of `list<int>`

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: [
  GoRoute(name: 'loading', path: '/', builder: (context, state) {
    //This is a mapper
    List<dynamic> temp = state.extra as List<dynamic>;
    List<int> genres = temp.map((item) => item as int).toList();
    return Loading(genres: genres);
  },
  ),

  ...

]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the following error message: `The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.`

Comment: @Duddy67 What is the type  `state.extra` ?

Comment: `state.extra.runtimeType` returns `Null`

Comment: @Duddy67 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74813803/13600868 Check this page.then I edit my answer

Comment: It throws an exception: `The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast` 
I think Gretal's suggestion is is the way to go: `List<int> genres = state.extra as List<int>? ?? [];`